# Helpful resource for django on google app engine beginner

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm a Beginner, trying to build a django project that runs on Google App Engine.
Since a Week,I'm trying to find a good resource that will get me up and running, but in vain. The official google app engine documentation itself is quiet outdated and whatever external resources I get is not relevant too. Trying them, ends up with a bunch of errors.

Kindly, point me to any Resource, Tutorial or anything that will get me started with deploying a django project in google app engine.

I'm using django version-1.3, since that's the latest supported version with google app engine version-1.6.5.

Help might be very useful.

Comment: In what way is the official GAE docs "outdated"? On the contrary, it's totally up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for docs on django-nonrel.  I don't know of much great documentation, but you can probably find docs pretty easily on Google.

The latest repo is here: https://github.com/django-nonrel

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Django is your best solution. It is a very good framework but I don't use it anymore for 2 main reasons:

1. It is bigger than other, and therefore heavier than you need.
2. It is not well supported in App Engine, so you have to use an old version (norel)

If you are a beginner, I would recommend you look this [open source project](http://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/README.rdoc) that has a lot of amazing features well implemented where you can learn how they do it.

That project is using the last technology supported in Google App Engine and has a lot of contributors.

Comment: In fact, django-nonrel is pretty up to date. Also, you don't know what is it that the asker needs - maybe he can live with Django being relatively heavy (is it?). Also, self-promotion.

Comment: Yes, maybe he can live with Django being relatively heavy

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [django-nonrel's documentation](http://django-nonrel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) if you haven't already. I remember having some trouble setting it up, but I'm afraid I can't recall what the exact problem was (you might need to run your dev server with `dev_appserver.py .` instead of `manage.py runserver`). Once I got it up and running, though, it worked like a charm.